# Process List asynchronously with SemaphoreSlim for throttling extension method

Tags: c#, thread-safety, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've got some methods that follow a similar pattern, and wanted to abstract some of the logic away into an extension method. Specifically, I am processing lists of objects with the TPL, and throttling that processing with a `SemaphoreSlim`.

```
public static Task ValidateProxiesAsync(IList<Proxy> proxies, IList<ProxyJudge> judges, IList<ProxyTest> tests)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await ValidateTestsAsync(judges.ToList<IProxyTest>());
        await ValidateTestsAsync(tests.ToList<IProxyTest>());
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var proxy in proxies)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                proxy.Status = proxy.TestValidity(judges[0]);
                semaphore.Release();
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    });
}

public static Task ValidateTestsAsync(IList<IProxyTest> tests)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                test.Status = test.TestValidity();
                semaphore.Release();
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    });
}
```

I wrote this extension method to reduce the LOC needed to do this. But I wanted to make sure I didn't overlook something. Perhaps there is a better solution that someone on here could suggest (TPL Dataflow?).

**Extension method:**

```
    public static Task ProcessWithSemaphoreAsync<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T> action, int maxConcurrency)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => {
            var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency);
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    action.Invoke(item);
                    semaphore.Release();
                }));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can see is that you should dispose the semaphore:

```
using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
{
  var tasks ....
}
```

And you could generalize to `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`

---

A simple solution using `Parallel.ForEach()` could be:

```
public static void ProcessWithParallelAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action, int maxConcurrency)
{
  ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
  options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConcurrency;
  Parallel.ForEach(list, options, action);
}
```

Or you could wrap it in a Task if you like:

```
public static Task ProcessWithParallelAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action, int maxConcurrency)
{
  return Task.Run(() =>
  {
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConcurrency;

    Parallel.ForEach(list, options, action);
  });
}
```

Comment: This does not work when the action itself must be asynchronous.